# Displaying image from database with bootstrap

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, bootstrap-4

My code for the picture below is this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I think it's okay to do it like that if the images are not called from the database. So my problem is, if i had several images in the database(MySQL) and want to call and display it as in the picture, what is the effective way to display them other than having to repeat the same code over and over. Am using bootstrap 3.3.7. Beginner here and would really appreciate some guidance, thanks.

Comment: How's your PHP?  A foreach loop can do this.

Comment: @Forbs i know that we could use the while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) loop to retrieve the images multiple time, the problem is how do i display those images in order as shown in the picture.

Comment: *Wow*. You have quite a few questions with what seem to be possible solutions. Have any of those solved them? They've been left unmarked and still considered as being open.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
    <?php
    include('conexion.php');

$query = "SELECT * from your_tables";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    echo ' <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
                <img src="'.$row["image"].'" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
            </div>';
    } <?
     </div>
    </div>
```